# D3 Hierarchical Edge Bundling

Tags: d3.js, charts

I'm currently looking at the following example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999. The json file which the chart is getting its data from is in the following format `{"name":"flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge","size":743,"imports":[]}];`

Instead of the above format, is it possible to have it as

```
{"imports":[],"name":"flare.analytics.cluster.MergeEdge","size":743};
```

Many thanks in advance for taking the time to read this.

Comment: The order of the keys is meaningless, so the 2 examples you provided are equivalent. What matters is the order in which you read those keys, not how they appear. If you're relying on a `for(var key in object) {...}` loop to read the keys — and that's the order you want to control — there's no way to do that and guarantee the same order in all browsers/platforms. [See more here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, D3.js get json data via your obj.name, so that's no matter how your json data sorting, I try a demo modify

```
{"name":"flare.vis.data.render.ArrowType", "size":698,"imports":[]}
```

to

```
{"size":698,"imports":[],"name":"flare.vis.data.render.ArrowType"}
```

and the graph still show out the same.